# How to stop python script from exiting when an error occurred while scraping data from website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python script to scrape data from website with a 1-minute interval. But sometimes error occurred and the script exit. Is there any way to avoid the script from exiting even after the error occurred?

My code:

```
 from requests
 import Session
 import pandas as pd
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re 

 def get_option_chain(symbol, expdate):

  if symbol == 'NIFTY':
  Base_url = ("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol="+symbol+"&date="+expdate)

  

  new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_hdrs_name)

 

  print(new_table)

  new_table.to_csv('Option_Chain_Table_{}.csv'.format(symbol))

 get_option_chain('NIFTY','17OCT2019')


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_option_chain,'NIFTY','17OCT2019')

while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Error:

```
Exception ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without 
response')) in getting data  for symbol NIFTY
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python\Python37\NSE scrape fata.py", line 70, in <module>
schedule.run_pending()
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 563, in run_pending
default_scheduler.run_pending()
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 94, in run_pending
 self._run_job(job)
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 147, in _run_job
 ret = job.run()
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 466, in run
 ret = self.job_func()
File "C:\Python\Python37\NSE scrape fata.py", line 41, in get_option_chain
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'page' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Are you going to show us the real code that caused the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `try...except`:

```py
from requests import Session
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re 
import time

def get_option_chain(symbol, expdate):
    if symbol == 'NIFTY':
        Base_url = ("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol="+symbol+"&date="+expdate)



new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_hdrs_name)


print(new_table)
new_table.to_csv('Option_Chain_Table_{}.csv'.format(symbol))

get_option_chain('NIFTY','17OCT2019')


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(get_option_chain,'NIFTY','17OCT2019')

while 1:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        continue
```

Also you did not import `time` module and used `time.sleep(1)`. So import time.
I recommend reading [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) as well.